# How to Determine If List of Values is in a Given Array

Tags: sql, hql, hive

Let's say I have a random list of 20 comma separated values.

And column_1 of table1 is an array that could contain one or more of these values.

```
column_1           
12345,98764,23456,87462
23456,82675,37562,38746
```

I would like to know if column_1 of table1 contains any of these said values.
If column_1 does contain one or more of those values, I would like the query to return that given row.

Does anyone know how to match a list of values with an array? I could manually do

```
WHERE column1 LIKE '%12345%'
   OR column1 LIKE '%23456%'
```

but that is not efficient at all..please help :)

Comment: this is a terrible way to store your data. having said that, you could do `where column1 regexp '12345|23456'`

Comment: actually i suppose it would be better if you did  `..where column1 regexp '[[:<:]](12345|23456)[[:>:]]'`

Comment: What is the datatype of this column? If you are using Hive then is column1 an Array[] type?